# how to execute code after async function in rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm probably missing some basic rust concept I know that but I don't know where to start.

So I have this websocket module which is working in ws.rs file

In my main.rs file I do this:

```
mod ws;

fn main(){
    ws::create();
    eprintln!("Some other code here...");
}
```

****Problem: Code after ws::create() is not executing****

So what's in create function :

```
// rest of the ws code module here

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn create() -> Result<(), IoError> {
    let addr ="0.0.0.0:8080".to_string();

    let state = PeerMap::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

    // Create the event loop and TCP listener we'll accept connections on.
    let try_socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await;
    let listener = try_socket.expect("Failed to bind");
    println!("Listening on: {}", addr);

    // Let's spawn the handling of each connection in a separate task.
    while let Ok((stream, addr)) = listener.accept().await {
        tokio::spawn(handle_connection(state.clone(), stream, addr));
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

So I know I'm missing something basic about async or this kind of function (async/while);; If anyone has an idea to how to handle this basic situation I'll be very grateful :) thanks !

EDIT:

to be more clear about what I want to do; after creating my websocket I instanciate something that get a stream of data (which is also async infinite) and I want to pass this stream to my websocket

```
mod ws;

fn main(){
    ws::create();
    // Here I receive a stream of data 
    // and I want to do something like ws::send(streamPayload)
}
```

Comment: `ws::create();` will block the current thread until spawned tasks in the runtime(which built with tokio::main) end,  but this code says: 
`while let Ok((stream, addr)) = listener.accept().await`, there will be always a new task spawned in the runtime to await a new connection.

Comment: yes that's what I thought but how to handle properly this situation ? what direction should I go/read ?

Comment: Your code after `ws::create()` does not run because that function does not return, so either make that function return or move the new code to before that function or into that function. I don't think random people on the Internet (we) will be able to guess the right choice without knowing more details about what you are trying to do.

Comment: There might be many suggestions according to your use case(for me it is not clear). Whats the exact point you want to execute the `eprintln!("Some other code here...");`, after bind or after first connection request or random ?

Comment: I edited my question,  after creating my websocket I instanciate something that get a stream of data (which is also async infinite) and I want to pass this stream to my websocket

Comment: If i understand correctly, you don't need multiple runtimes, this [proxy example](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/examples/proxy.rs) might be a solution to your problem.

Comment: honestly I don't know I just feel I should open several threads but I'm not used to thread concept

Answer (score 0):

Ok my question was probably not clear or the answer was too obvious I don't know but the only thing I needed is to put another thread this way:

```
fn main(){

    let wsThread = thread::spawn(|| {
        ws::create(tx);
    });

    println!("some other code");
    wsThread.join().unwrap();
}
```